# Set PowerShell "Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB" using Group Policy

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

I want to apply the following PowerShell settings on many servers:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 12345
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 12345
```

I found https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh751276(v=sc.12).aspx and tested that the `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Remote Shell\Specify maximum amount of memory in MB per Shell` setting changes `localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB`, but is there a way to change `localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the value on a test system using the PS commands you listed and then go into the registry to:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Plugin\Microsoft.Powershell
```

There find the key `ConfigXML` and copy the Value.  Use this value in a GPO that sets Computer Configuration, Preferences, Registry.

Comment: Thanks, that does have the value (`<Quotas MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024" ...`) but I'm reluctant to overwrite that whole XML string, not knowing what else I might change, not to mention that stuff is probably subject to change without notice. If there is no GPO setting for this I might just have to run a PowerShell script to make the change.

Comment: @EM0 then consider writing a script to remotely run the two `Set-Item` commands on each server.